# Google Cloud Vision doesn't return MRZ

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision

I've tested with multiple images and is curious that it doesn't return MRZ code. I've used same image with ABBYY or Pixlab and both returns MRZ (at least partially)

Does GCV has any restriction or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Using [DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-fulltext) I was able to get the MRZ in unicode character.